# Android take photo and create small gallery with photos in Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview, android-camera

I'm building an activity where the user presses a button and it takes them to a screen where they can take a photo using the default camera app, then add it to a bitmap List for object storage later. It also displays these photos taken on the Activity screen. However the way I currently have it set up in a way that it only allows for a single imageview photo to appear, and I want to make it so the user can keep taking photos and it will keep displaying them on the activity but will also keep adding them to the list. 
Here is code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ImageView ivThumbnailPhoto;
    Bitmap bitMap;
    static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnTackPic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTakePic);
        ivThumbnailPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivThumbnailPhoto);

        if(hasCamera()){
            tvHasCamera.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
            tvHasCamera.setText("You have Camera");
        }

        if(hasDefualtCameraApp(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)){
            tvHasCameraApp.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
            tvHasCameraApp.setText("You have Camera Apps");
        }

        btnTackPic.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode== RESULT_OK && intent != null){
            // get bundle
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            // get bitmap
            bitMap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ivThumbnailPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitMap);

        }
    }

    private boolean hasCamera(){
        return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
    }

    private boolean hasDefualtCameraApp(String action){
        final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        return list.size() > 0;

    }
}
```

Layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnailPhoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/takePicButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Take a Picture" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm assuming that I can use Gallery instead of ImageView to do this but I am having difficulty implementing such a solution so any help would be great
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can using uri  for display on activity after decode it to bitmap

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        ImageView ivThumbnailPhoto;
        Bitmap bitMap;
        static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            btnTackPic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTakePic);
            ivThumbnailPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivThumbnailPhoto);

            if(hasCamera()){
                tvHasCamera.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
                tvHasCamera.setText("You have Camera");
            }

            if(hasDefualtCameraApp(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)){
                tvHasCameraApp.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
                tvHasCameraApp.setText("You have Camera Apps");
            }

            btnTackPic.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
           startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), TAKE_PICTURE);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

            if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode== RESULT_OK && intent != null){

                // get Uri
                ivThumbnailPhoto.setImageUri(intent.getData());

            }
        }

        private boolean hasCamera(){
            return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
        }

        private boolean hasDefualtCameraApp(String action){
            final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
            List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

            return list.size() > 0;

        }
    }
```